# One excess element in the array is always left

Tags: python, arrays, element

I'm working on a validator of credit cards. That sphere is new for me, so please, don't laugh:D
I'm trying to finish it without any libraries.

```
def creditCardValidation(creditcard):
    creditcard = creditcard.replace( ' ', '' )
    creditcard = [int(i) for i in creditcard]
    evens = creditcard[::2]
    odds = creditcard[1::2]
    evens = [element * 2 for element in evens]

    for j in evens:
        if j >= 10:
            j = [int(d) for d in str(j)]
            for x in j:
                evens.append(x)

    for j in evens:
       if j >= 10:        
            evens.remove(j)
    return ((sum(evens) + sum(odds)) % 10 == 0)
```

`creditCardValidation('1234 5678 9101 1213')`

`creditCardValidation('4561 2612 1234 5464')`

`creditCardValidation('4561 2612 1234 5467')`

So the problem is in the array **evens**.
It returns

`[2, 6, 14, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 8]`

`[8, 4, 2, 2, 6, 12, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]`

`[8, 4, 2, 2, 6, 12, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]`

It should return the same results except those which greater than 10. Everything works fine. Take a look at the first array, 18 deleted as well as 10, but 14 is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing while iterating over the array is not the best thing to do and will mostly result in skipping some elements in the array while iterating, so a safer way to do this

```
    for j in evens:
       if j >= 10:        
            evens.remove(j)
```

is to collect all the elements you want to remove in another list then subtract it from your original if you are using `numpy arrrays` or removing them one by one, as python lists has no subtraction operation defined to subtract one array from a another

```
to_remove = []
for j in evens:
  if j >= 10:        
    to_remove.append(j)
for j in to_remove:
  events.remove(j)
```

or you could whitelist instead of blacklisting

```
small_evens = []
for j in evens:
  if j < 10:        
    small_evens.append(j)
# use small_evens and discard evens array
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

- Python has zero indexed arrays, so `evens[::2]` is actually returning the first, third, etc. digit. Luhn's algo requires even digits (assuming 1 indexing) to be doubled.
- You shouldn't modify a list you are iterating over.

You can simplify, removing a lot of the list creations:

```
def creditCardValidation(creditcard):
    *creditcard, checkdigit = creditcard.replace(' ', '')

    total = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(map(int, creditcard), 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            digit *= 2
            total += digit // 10   # Will be zero for single digits
        total += digit % 10

    return 9*total % 10 == int(checkdigit)

In []:
creditCardValidation('1234 5678 9101 1213')

Out[]:
True

In []:
creditCardValidation('4561 2612 1234 5464')

Out[]:
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this model doesn't return correct answer anyway.

Comment: If you are using Luhn's algo then usually the `total` is multiplied `9` and uses the last digit as a check digit. Updated!